# explanation of the use of literal control in playing a video on asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net

can some one please explain me how a literal control plays a video file in asp.net, I have used it bu want to know the back end logic. I have provided the path of the video from database after that what happens at the processing time.

Comment: [LiteralControl: "Represents HTML elements, text, and any other strings in an ASP.NET page that do not require processing on the server."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.literalcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) - it seems to just append whatever HTML you provide it with.

Comment: but how it plays a video on the page??

Comment: Presumably with a [video tag](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp)?

Comment: "I have used It" ..... it would easier for us to answer if you show an example of how you have used it.

Answer (score 2):

`Literal` control will not play video automatically,  `Literal` is more of a placeholder where you can set any `html` you want. `Literal` itself will not render any tag in `HTML` if the text is not provided.

`Literal` Control represents `HTML` elements, text, and any other strings in an `ASP.NET` page that do not require processing on the server.

You can also use `Literal` to inject the HTML used to play video like following.

```
    string videoString = "";
    videoString += "<video width='400' controls>";
    videoString += "<source src='YOUR_VIDE_URL' type='video/ogg' />";
    videoString += "Your browser does not support HTML5 video.";      
    videoString += "</video>";
    Literal1.Text = videoString;
```

Above code will render the HTML video at the place of Literal.